# AWS Lambda/Nodejs is not executing mysql connection.query

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple Lambda function to connect to MYSQL, but the `connection.query` is not executing.
Lambda has `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` access and it is part of the same VPC where RDS is deployed.

RDS security group is added to Lambda's configuration. log1 is the output that I always get. One time i got Log2. I am not sure what is going on.

```js
    var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
      user     : 'admin',
      password : 'pass',
      database : 'dbname'
    });
    console.log('CONNECTION ' + connection);
    connection.connect();
    console.log('2 ');  
    exports.handler = async (event,context,callback) => {
      console.log('3 ');
      context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
        connection.query('SELECT emp_num from tag where emp_id=1', function (error, results, fields) {
          console.log('2 ');
          if (error) throw error;
          else
            callback(null, results)
          //console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].tag_num);
        });
        connection.end();
    };
```

Log1

> START RequestId: 04c2d758-ac40-474f-ac55-045ccea8a9ff Version: $LATEST
> 2020-11-08T02:02:58.976Z  04c2d758-ac40-474f-ac55-045ccea8a9ff    INFO    3
> END RequestId: 04c2d758-ac40-474f-ac55-045ccea8a9ff REPORT RequestId:
> 04c2d758-ac40-474f-ac55-045ccea8a9ff  Duration: 5.75 ms   Billed
> Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 20 MB

Log2

> START RequestId: abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe Version: $LATEST
> 2020-11-08T02:02:43.293Z  abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe    INFO    3
> 2020-11-08T02:02:43.294Z  abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe    INFO    2
> 2020-11-08T02:02:43.294Z  abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe    ERROR   Uncaught
> Exception     {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"Cannot enqueue Query
> after invoking
> quit.","code":"PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_QUIT","fatal":false,"stack":["Error:
> Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.","    at
> Protocol._validateEnqueue
> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:215:16)","
> at Protocol._enqueue
> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:138:13)","
> at Connection.query
> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)","    at
> Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:18:16)","    at
> Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]} [ERROR]
> [1604800963301] LAMBDA_RUNTIME Failed to post handler success
> response. Http response code: 403. END RequestId:
> abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe REPORT RequestId:
> abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe  Duration: 29.47 ms  Billed
> Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 20 MB
> RequestId: abeb6a6d-7480-4acc-91e2-5971e6fe74fe Error: Runtime exited
> with error: exit status 129 Runtime.ExitError

Answer (score 3):

Your handle is defined to be `async` and you didn't `await` to the promise.
Possible solutions:

1. Add await call to your promise (i.e. `await connection.query(...).promise()`)
2. Change the handler's signature to be non-async (i.e. `exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {...}`) and then it will wait to the callback.
3. (Ugly workaround) Add `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;`, which tells AWS to wait for an empty event loop.

Disclosure: I work for Lumigo, a company that helps you to debug serverless applications.